# Any candidate remedies for Blender 3.1 Crash Wont Start?

Tags: startup-file

Blender 3.1 Windows 11

Contents of blender_debug_output.txt

> I0408 XX:15:33.568084 22400 device.cpp:45] CUEW initialization succeeded

> I0408 XX:15:33.568084 22400 device.cpp:47] Found precompiled kernels

> I0408 XX:15:33.590776 22400 device.cpp:68] HIPEW initialization failed: Error opening HIP dynamic library

Blender worked to 90% in 8 hours previous to the current problem. In the current situation Blender starts for (.5) seconds with  little OS indications then disappears.

Of course, reinstallation looms.
Any recommended actions? Thanks.

Comment: [T93888](https://developer.blender.org/T93888) seems to be a known problem that the developers can't reproduce, so maybe a reinstall won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Blender launching it from a command prompt. Not a real solution but at least a valid workaround.
If it works you can make this workaround smarter with the following steps:

1. create a file named "blender.cmd" within the blender installation directory

with the following content:

```
@echo off
start blender.exe %*
```

2. then edit the links to blender changing the destination from blender.exe to blender.cmd
3. to restore the link icon choose "change icon", browse to blender installation folder and select blender.exe, pick the icon, then confirm.
4. if the problem happens even when double-clicking .blend files, change the default program from blender.exe to blender.cmd (unforunately doing this .blend files will lose the icon).